# Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: /data/app/myapp.apk failed verification of META-INF/CERT.SF

Tags: android

I have an app released on the Play Store that works fine on most devices but I've had 16 users (according to Crashlytics) who have had this strange crash:

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: /data/app/mypackage.apk failed verification of META-INF/CERT.SF
       at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.failedVerification(JarVerifier.java:136)
       at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.verifyCertificate(JarVerifier.java:305)
       at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.readCertificates(JarVerifier.java:258)
       at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:378)
       at libcore.net.url.JarURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(JarURLConnectionImpl.java:226)
       at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:436)
       at java.util.ResourceBundle.handleGetBundle(ResourceBundle.java:514)
       at java.util.ResourceBundle.handleGetBundle(ResourceBundle.java:541)
       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:227)
       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:140)
       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.(GenericServlet.java:95)
       at MyApplication.createHttpServer(MyApplication.java:270)
       at MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:253)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1014)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4225)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:140)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1288)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Any idea why this would only be affecting a small percentage of my users? it seems to be mostly Android 4.0, 4.1.1 and 4.1.2.

Thanks.